# Django- How to hide a button from a superuser or admin but show it to regular or active users

Tags: django, django-templates

I want to hide a button from a Django Admin or superuser but I want to display it if the user is not an Admin or superuser.
How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Superusers have a is_superuser attribute attached to request.user, so you can check whether or not a user is a super user by making a block in your template that asks:

```
{% if request.user.is_superuser == False %}

<button>My button</button>

{% endif %}
```

Similarly, admins (or as Django calls them, 'staff') also have an is_staff attribute set to a boolean value.